# PHP selectfield get value from database, change and POST

Tags: php, select, field

I'm a beginner with PHP and have some decent issues ^^

Would like to pick the data from the field "disabled" from the database and update the selectfield with the value.

The selectfield has 2 possible options "yes" and "no" (value 0 or 1).
Now i would finally like to post the selected or unchanged value back to the database.

Here all the values including **disabled** which are loaded into $row by MYSQL SELECT query

```
 $mydb->query('SELECT a.* ...
 $row = $mydb->fetchRow();
```

Here the working query to write into the database / table (tested on other fields).
**disabled** is the field that should be updated/overwritten:

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO `api_tokens` (`id`, `disabled`) VALUES (
                ".$id.",
                ".(empty($_POST['disabled']) ? 0 : 1).")";
```

Here the form which should have 2 selectable options, one of them shoudl be the value loaded from the database and the other value should be the opposite.
Unclear value/ares is marked with ????

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="disabled">Deactivate</label>
    <select name="disabled" id="disabled">
        <option selected="<?=$row['disabled']?>"></option>
        <option value="????">No</option>
        <option value="????">Yes</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: If you're reading the value from the database to initialize your form with previously chosen values, then you should be `SELECT`ing values. `REPLACE INTO` is a _write_ operation. Please share your full code for context. Also, typical values for a boolean (yes/no) form input are 1/0, on/off. Usually, for boolean inputs, a `checkbox` is the appropriate type. If you're using a select box to present unambiguous labels (yes/no vs. tick mark), then consider changing that to radio buttons. The options will be more discoverable, which will lead to a better UX.

Comment: Yes first i want to read the values from the table which is done with SELECT*, load it into the form which i tried with <?=$row['disabled']?>   which contains the value 0. i know 0 and 1 aren't optimal for that case but it is an already existing production database.

Comment: 0 and 1 are ok for a boolean field. 0 means false and 1 true. But your question is completely unclear. your query has little meaning compared to what you are asking

Comment: Uhm ok. Well the field of the table disabled can contain a 0 or a 1. I want to load this actual value from the field into the form. Now the user can leave it, or select a 1 and submit it to store it in the field of the table.

Comment: my bad...i just updated the query to write into the database (yes overwite is wanted in this special case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The key is to check the value for each condition. If the saved choice was 'no' (0) then set the `select` attribute. Do the same for 'yes' (1).

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="disabled">Deactivate</label>
    <select name="disabled" id="disabled">
        <option value="0"<?php echo ($row['disabled'] == 0?' selected':''); ?>>No</option>
        <option value="1"<?php echo ($row['disabled'] == 1?' selected':''); ?>>Yes</option>
    </select>
```

### UPDATE

I see from your comment that you'd like additional clarification. Here's what happens:

1. Each `<option>` element will specify a `value` attribute as one possible choice of the `<select>` element it belongs to. When a choice is made, the `<option>` element's `selected` attribute is set. (Technically, there is the `multiple` attribute on the `<select>` element, but let's not get into that now.)
2. When your user submits the form, their choices (option values) are made persistent by storing them in a database. In this example, this will be *either* `1` for yes or `0` for no.
3. If you want to present the user with the *last state* their form was in, you have to read their choices back from the database. You now have to set the `select` attribute on the `<option>` element they chose before. On their screen, their chosen option is now highlighted in the `<select>` list.

You can find the choice they submitted in `$row['disabled']`, where the `'disabled'` key is equal to the `name` attribute of the `<select>` element. To set the `select` attribute on the right (previously chosen) `<option>` element, you check `$row['disabled']` against each `<option>` element's value. Are they equal? Then this was their last chosen option, so now highlight it and set the `selected` attribute on this specific `<option>` element.

Comment: Yes! you got my upvote. He should just bear in mind not to keep this same approach when listing lots of options from the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Still very complicated for me ^^ So in the first line of the options: value of the field is 0 by default and we compare the value of ['disabled'] with 0. If that is the case we set it to 'selected' to "mark that in the select field in the browser ?

Comment: Yes. I fleshed out my answer with some additional explanation, hoping this will give a deeper insight.